# Shell: Get current version number of latest docker library image

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I would like to get the current version number of latest version of some docker library images.

*Examples:*

- 'docker' should give me: `17.09.0-ce`, `17.09.0`, `17.09`, `17`, `stable`, `test`, `edge` (https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/)
- 'mongo' should give me: `3.4.9`, `3.4`, `3` (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)

I tried to do it this way:

```
curl -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mongo/tags/' | jq '."results"[]["name"]' | tr -d '"'
```

But that doesn't give me the needed result.

Comment: What is the output you are getting for `curl -s 'https://registry.hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/mongo/tags/'` and what is the output you need from it?

Comment: Probably because those tags are in page 2 for `mongo`.